# iOS, in app purchases - "Waiting for Review"

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Quick question, if my in-app purchases are listed on iTunes Connect as "Waiting for Review", should I be able to test them in a sandbox environment? Atm I'm getting an error that no products are available, but I'd like to make sure it's because of that and not an error on my end, just to speed things up. I'm using Unity to build my app and the store is built using their tutorial that can be found here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game . The store does work on Android just fine btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well usually before you submit your app and your IAP too Apple to review everything and accept it you're supposed to have tested all your IAP and taken screenshots of them working.

So yes they should work before they're even sent to be reviewed.

You might want to follow those steps to make sure you've set everything up correctly : [Adding In-App Purchase to your Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html)

Comment: You were right! I was missing my tax documents. Thanks!

Comment: @stefanplc Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of that if your app uses a brand new IAP but is not reviewed yet, your new release will crash immediately after it launches.
The experience was expensive for me :)

So, first make the IAP got approved. Then publish the build.